# translating vertical bars to horizontal bars in c programming

Tags: c

I want to make a program where I send in a list of numbers indicating the heights of bars. For example, “1 5 3” would mean a bar of length 1 followed by a bar of height 5 and then 3. I want this to be translated into sideways bars and their positions. “1 5 3” would be a bar of length 3 followed by a bar of length 2, another 2, a 1, and another 1. This would be denoted “[0,3)@1”, where 1 is the height, 0 is the beginning, and 3 is where it ends. The other 4 are “[1,3)@2”, “[1,3)@3”, “[1,2)@4”, and “[1,2)@5”.

Does somebody have a rough idea of how to this? A sort of idea like a psuedo code would be already great so I know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Read inputs, producing:
    W, the number of inputs.
    H, the maximum input.
    Heights, an array with the height of each bar, starting with index 0.
For y from 0 to H-1:
    Set CurrentState to Empty.
    For x from 0 to W-1:
        If CurrentState is Empty:
            If y < Heights[x]:
                Set CurrentState to Occupied.
                Print "[", x, and ",".
        Else:
            If Heights[x] <= y:
                Set CurrentState to Empty.
                Print x, ")@", y, and end-of-line or other desired delimiter.
```

The basic idea is to scan across each row and: Where bars start, print the starting coordinate. Where bars have ended, print the ending coordinate, along with the current vertical position.